# Apply css display:none on button

Tags: html, css

It seems I can use `display: none;` on a `button`.
I can use `visibility: hidden;` but it doesn't do exactly what I want since the button is still present (just not display). Any other way I could remove a button using css only ?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/jf8mkerr/)

Comment: What is it you want to accomplish? Why isn't `display: none` a good solution?

Comment: I just want to use display: none, the only thing is when I set : 
<button style='display: none></button>
It doesn't work

Comment: is the missing closing quote only in the comment, or in your code, as well? can you post the code you have?

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<button style='display: none></button>
```

To This

```
<button style='display: none;'></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a class in css file assuming it will be `style.css`

```
.nodisplay {
     display:none;
}
```

and in your button

```
<button class="nodisplay"></button>
```

This way you can use the `nodisplay` class where ever you want on your site and no need to define `style='display: none;'` again and again in different HTML elements you want to hide